# Only get part out of data-attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, html

I only want to get the hours out of this:

```
data-timestamp="2014/04/01 10:50:01";

$(items).each(function(){
    var timestamp = $(this).data('timestamp');
    $(this).wrap("<div class='" + timestamp + "'></div>");
});
```

this wraps all the items inside their own timestamp so `class="2014/04/01 10:50:01"`
So the wrapping part should only wrap the timestamp hours so 10 `class="10"` - I can't figure out how to do this.

items is an array with divs they all contain the timestamps with different times.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: @BenM - can't you see what he has tried so far? and where he is stuck?

Comment: @Darren Nope, I don't see any attempt at retrieving the hours at all.

Comment: Apart from him showing what he has and saying he is stuck.. anymore code and he would have his own answer.... not sure what he could have possibly put if he has no idea what to do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could turn your string date into an actual date:

`var d = Date(timestamp);`

And then get the hours from the `d` date

`var hour = d.getHours();`

So your code becomes something like:

```
 $(items).each(function(){
      var hour = new Date($(this).data('timestamp')).getHours();
      $(this).wrap("<div class='" + hour + "'></div>");
 });
```

Or to look a little less complicated

```
 $(items).each(function(){      
      var date = new Date($(this).data('timestamp')); // turn into a date
      var hour = date.getHour(); // get the hour 0 = midnight
      $(this).wrap("<div class='" + hour + "'></div>");
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the build-in Date formatting in Javascript, and then use the method .getHours() on this data-object.

```
$(items).each(function(){
        var timestamp = $(this).data('timestamp');
var d = new Date(timestamp);

        $(this).wrap("<div class='" + d.getHours()+ "'></div>");
    });
```

Comment: Why `+1` on the hours?? - 0 = midnight, 23 = eleven o'clock

Comment: Maybe confused with months where 0=Jan ?

Comment: Indeed :) confusion with months

Answer (score 0):

If your format is always the same and don't want to parse it as a date, you could use substring:

```
$(items).each(function(){
    var timestamp = $(this).data('timestamp').substr(11, 2);
    $(this).wrap("<div class='" + timestamp + "'></div>");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [`.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

```
$(items).each(function () {
    var timestamp = $(this).data('timestamp');
    timestamp = timestamp.split(" ");
    timestamp = timestamp[1].split(":");
    timestamp = timestamp[0];

    $(this).wrap("<div class='" + timestamp + "'></div>");
});
```